# cmd command start can't work with the new version of mingw32-make.exe?

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

```
# Makefile
run: a.exe
    start cmd /c "a.exe & pause"
a.exe: main.cpp Makefile
    g++ main.cpp
```

this makefile works well with my old version "mingw32-make.exe", the version is

```
> mingw32-make -v
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
etc.
```

today I met a new software called mysy2, I download the last mingw32 with it. and the file makefile, don't works anymore. the version info is:

```
> mingw32-make -v
GNU Make 4.1.90
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
etc.
```

when I run the new mingw32-make with the makefile, it just say

```
> mingw32-make
start cmd /c "a.exe & pause"
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, start cmd /c "a.exe & pause", ...) failed.
make (e=2): 系统找不到指定的文件。#it is "system can't find the file" in chinese
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 2
```

anybody?

Comment: Just wondering: why are you always using prerelease versions of GNU make instead of final release versions (in GNU make, all versions x.y.9z are considered alpha/beta/release candidate releases)?  Where are you downloading these?

Comment: @MadScientist The first is a part of "codeblocks with mingw for windows", codeblocks is a cross platform c/c++ IDE. the second one is download within msys2, msys2 is a "pacman+bash" on windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I just deleted all the GNU make comes with MingW, and go to [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) download the last version on the web page, which is 3.81 for now, and very likely will not update it forever.

Comment: I think you should change your statement, that "codeblocks" (whatever that is) or "msys2" don't care about GNU make for Windows, if they're providing pre-release versions of software as final versions, especially where the actual release was made months ago.  GNU make is not provided (by the FSF) as a pre-built binary on _ANY_ system, not just Windows; it's only provided as source code.  You can build it yourself on Windows, just like you can build it yourself on any non-Windows system.  It's true that Windows is treated the same as other systems: that doesn't mean it's "hated".

Comment: @MadScientist Editing has been done. Thank you for clearing up the conceptions about GNU make in my mind, I really appreciate. Thank you!